# Deny login if session exists in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php login system implemented in my script. How would I make a script that denies a user to login if there is an existing session in the database?

For example,

User 1 logs into system > Login accepted
User 2 logs into system with same account as user 1 > Denies because another session exists.

that's how I want it to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Good. Which part are you stuck?

Comment: You, uhm, check the database for an existing session and, uhm, deny the login if any is found?

Comment: which code could I use to re-direct the user to another page if there is another session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question.

**If you are refering to PHP session:** You could store the session ID (and last access time) in a database, and reject login attempts for users with different session IDs if the last-access time is too recent(say, within the past 20 minutes). Clear the ID on logout, of course.

Note, though, if a user closes their browser without logging out and then reopens it, they may well be locked out for a while (the 20 minutes above, or whatever interval you decide on), since they won't have the matching session cookie anymore.

**If you are refering to DB session:** You have to configure the `Setting Account Resource Limits` in your Mysql DB like in this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-resources.html). But the problem here is that the number of simultaneous connections to the server by an account is available only as of MySQL 5.0.3.

**If you are refering to REAL-TIME cheking** then you can use [COMET Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) to push data to a browser, without the browser explicitly requesting it.

Comment: when someone logs in it records the session. If a user is inactive a cron script will clear their session every 5 minuets. I need the CODE to block them out though.

Comment: When a same user login for the next lets say 20mins then the user from the other PC with unique IP will be notified. like in facebook.

Comment: I dont want notification; I want to log the other one out.

Comment: You can log the one out by pushing data to the other PC. Even without notification, you can run a script that will log the user out after pushing the data.

Comment: which code can I use to push the data to log out? I've never coded in comet.

Comment: you can start [here](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start)

Answer (score 1):

store your sessionId in your db and then reject the login attempts for users with different sessionID if the last access time is recent(calculate by finding the difference between the last login time to current time).clear ID on logout

Answer (score 0):

There should be a new field in your users table which named as logged_in. When authenticating check this field what value it has.

If it is 0 / false let the user log in and set the logged_in field to 1/true.

else if logged_in field is 1/true do not let the second user log in.

**Do not forget to set the logged_in field to 0/false when logging out.**

Comment: What if user simply close his browser? Without clicking logout.

Comment: I did not think about that thanks. Some sort of punishment system may be triggered here. If the user closes the window without logging out which we can check this by js/ajax, next time he will has to wait (for example) 6 hours, and update the field as 0/false. Or the second user will have to wait until session expires.

Comment: I was planing to store sessions in the database and clear inacive user sessions every 5 minuets using a cron job.

Answer (score 0):

For that

you have to store `session` values in database. and then when other user login with same details. you can check it from database that already one user online with same login details

Answer (score 0):

I would place another field into database called, for instance, last_seen. Each time logged in user produce request - just put current date into that field.

When someone tries to log in - just check how long ago user were seen on site. If more than session timeout time (20 minutes by default) - you may consider that users is logged out and allow login.

Otherwise - deny login.

You can't figure out for sure if user is still using your site or no. You may put 1/0 in some field when user logs in/out, but nobody can guaranty that user will click logout link before closing tab.

But you may improve behavior of your site by setting that new field to null when user clicks logout link. Otherwise it may happen that someone logged out and now tries to do login again, but can't do that because system still handle his account as being used.

Comment: when someone logs in it records the session. If a user is inactive a cron script will clear their session every 5 minuets. I need the CODE to block them out though.

Comment: Your session is stored in database, correct? If so, you may add there another column which will keep id of user session belongs to. And than just check if there is a session with ID of users who just tried to log in.

Comment: I know all that; I just need php code written up to deny the user.